Why does flying at higher altitudes generally improve fuel efficiency for commercial airplanes given Specific Fuel Consumption rate (SFC)?
I’m a high school physics student with an interest in aviation and would like to understand why commercial airplanes fly at high altitudes (e.g., 35,000 feet) to improve fuel efficiency. My understanding is one of the primary reasons modern commercial planes fly so high (35000 feet at Mach 0.85) is because at higher altitudes due to less dense air there is less drag. Which means for the same amount of thrust you can fly faster (here talking about true air speed or ground speed). So far am I being clear?
Lets use some hypothetical numbers in a toy example. Let us say for the same amount of thrust (300 kN HYPOTHETICAL toy number) a airplane can go 400 kmph TAS (assume same as ground speed)  at 15000 feet, but  for  the same 300 kN thrust can go 800 kmph at 35000 feet. Let us say the airplane has to cover a distance of 1600 km. The plane at altitude 15000 feet can cover this distance in 4 hours while the plane at 35000 feet in 2 hours. How does this help fuel efficiency (in terms of Liters/km, gallons/mile)?
To generate the same amount of thrust (lets say 300 kN as a toy number) requires a certain number of fuel consumption rate (g/second Liters/Minute.)... I think the amount of thrust you get for a specific fuel consumption rate is called the Specific Fuel Consumption (SFC) which is the inverse of specific impulse (isp). I realize at higher altitude the density of fuel changes too this affects consumption, but let us assume they are approximately equal..i.e approximately same fuel per unit time is consumed to generate the same amount of thrust (300 kN) whether at 15000 feet or 35000 feet. That is for the purpose of this question I am assuming TFSC remains relatively constant with altitude.
Since the plane at 35000 feet will cover its 1600 km trip in less time based on its speed of 800 kmph it will have to maintain the 300 kN force for less time,  leading to less fuel consumption, leading to less fuel per distance (kg/hour, or Liters/Km)? In other words, if the airplane at 35,000 feet needs to maintain 300 kN thrust for less time to cover the same distance, does this translate to lower fuel consumption per unit distance?
This  is a highly simplified but is this approximately on the correct track (I made an assumption of constant fuel consumption rate at different altitude,ignored things like engine efficiency improving at higher altitude compounding the gains, and probably many unstated assumptions..)?

It is similar but not the same. It touches on TSFC, but assumes for this question it remains constant  with altitude (while acknowledging in reality it probably doesn't, and TSFC actually improves, further compounding gains in fuel mileage). It is a more basic question.

The atmosphere gets colder up to about 11km (36,089ft).  From there, the temperature stays the same for quite a while (in airplane terms).
Because the input air is colder, the engine can add heat more efficiently -- and add more heat before reaching the engine's maximum temperature limit.
This results in the TSFC (thrust specific fuel consumption) of a jet engine scaling with the square root of the temperature ratio.
$\mathrm{TSFC}=\mathrm{TSFC}_0 \sqrt{\theta}$
Where
$\mathrm{TSFC}$ is the thrust specific fuel consumption at altitude
$\mathrm{TSFC}_0$ is the $\mathrm{TSFC}$ at sea level
$\theta=T/T_{sl}$ is the temperature ratio at altitude to sea level.
So, $\mathrm{TSFC}$ gets better as long as the temperature drops (until 36,000 ft) and then it doesn't get better anymore.  This is why most transport aircraft fly at this altitude.

Here is a simpler way of thinking about this, in which Rob Mcdonald's correct answer is deeply embedded.
Flying higher means less drag, so you go faster on the same amount of horsepower. This means less time spent in the air with the engines burning, which means better fuel mileage and lower costs.
But flying higher also means less air to burn your fuel in, which means less horsepower. But if your engine has a big compressor in it, it has the capacity to jam more air into the engine despite the altitude and thus full horsepower is maintained at high altitude without running the engine past its maximum temperature limits.
There comes a point however when the big compressor is no longer capable of keeping up with the thinning air and flying above that altitude causes a loss of engine power, and the plane therefore loses speed as it gains altitude. So you add pitch-up trim to make the wings generate more lift for you, so you can climb into less-draggy air and counteract the fact that you are going slower.
Finally there comes the point where the wing is pitched up enough to be on the verge of a stall and the engines cannot develop enough power to fly any faster to escape the stall, and at that point you are mushing along as economically as possible. At this point the only way to add altitude is to decrease the plane's weight, which it does by burning off fuel. So, on a long flight you gradually add altitude as your weight goes down and thereby seek out and hold onto the max economy condition for as long as you can, all the while watching your engine temps.
The fact that all modern airliners have very similar max economy points is because they all use more or less the same engine technology.
Finally, note that it costs extra fuel to hoist a plane high into the air, and you have to make up for that fuel cost by cruising at max economy for a certain duration. There may not be enough flight time available at max altitude to pay for the climb, and so for any stage length there will be an optimum (lowest overall cost) cruise altitude which will be lower for shorter flights.
Since those short flights do not require a 40,000 foot cruise, they are serviced with smaller planes that fly lower and slower.
